# Liquibase scripts are not getting executed during redeployment of .ear file

Tags: database, h2, liquibase

I have a Liquibase script to add two tables in H2 database. First time when the .ear file is deployed, the scripts run and the tables are created. Afterwards I have dropped both tables from H2 database. When I redeploy the same .ear file, the system reads the scripts, but the tables are not generated. Following is the log details

```
INFO 10.10.14 14:03:liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
INFO 10.10.14 14:03:liquibase: Reading from DATABASE CHANGELOG
INFO 10.10.14 14:03:liquibase: Reading from DATABASE CHANGELOG
INFO 10.10.14 14:03:liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
```

Please provide me any tips why the tables are not created. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Liquibase stores in the very same DB the informations about the applied changes (in the mentioned DATABASE CHANGELOG).  Liquibase does not (and most certain can not) ensure, that the DB is in a state defined by the applied changes, but relies on it, that there are no magic changes from a third party. Drop or truncate Liquibases tables and you will see the changes will be applied again.